# Get selected row from OrderList PrimeFaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

Everything works fine (action get called, ui render correctly, etc...). Except I keep getting NullPointerException when I'm trying to get the selected object (even if I set it with the setPropertyActionListener)... How can I actually get the row I click on orderList. I've done a converter, but stil bring me no where.

```
<p:orderList value="#{userProfileModel.personnalTaskMacroList}" 
    var="personnalTaskMacro" iconOnly="true" effect="clip"
    itemValue="#{personnalTaskMacro}" converter="personnalTaskMacroConverterId" 
    controlsLocation="right" id="personnalTaskMacroList">

  <p:column style="width:50%;">
    #{personnalTaskMacro.taskMacro.macroTitle}
  </p:column>

  <p:column style="width:30%;">
    #{personnalTaskMacro.isFavorite}
  </p:column>

  <p:column style="width:20%;">
    <p:commandButton id="addTaskMacroToFavoriteCommandButton" 
        action="userProfile.addTaskMacroToFavorite"
        onclick="jQuery.simpleBlockUI();cleanWatermark();"
        oncomplete="jQuery.unblockUI();showWatermark();"
        onerror="jQuery.unblockUI();" icon="ui-icon-search">
      <f:setPropertyActionListener
          target="#{userProfileModel.selectedPersonnalTaskMacro}"
          value="#{personnalTaskMacro}" />       
    </p:commandButton>
  </p:column>
</p:orderList>
```

I use webflow to handle action (xml).

```
 <transition on="userProfile.addTaskMacroToFavorite">
 <evaluate      expression="extUserProfileController.addTaskMacroToFavorite(userProfileModel)"/>
            <render fragments="userProfilePersonnalMacrosFragment" />
 </transition>
```

Comment: In `commandButton` you have `action="userProfile.addTaskMacroToFavorite"`. Didn't you want to call some backing bean method, something like `action="#{userProfile.addTaskMacroToFavorite}"`? Can you show us relevant methods from backing bean?

Comment: I'm using spring-webflow to handle transition. So, the actual action is linked to the xml.

Comment: What is scope of your backing bean?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and basically, It's not a data component, you can't use f:setPropertyActionListener. :/

http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2713